# MenuItems(MediaRouterActoinProvider) are not being displayed from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, chromecast, shareactionprovider

I need to display `MediaRouterActionProvider` as a menu item and have it displayed in the action bar of **Main Activity** which extends `FragmentActivity()`;

The setup:

```
mainMenu.xml
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

```
private void setUpActionBar() {
    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setTitle("MediaRouter");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}
```

I’m unable to display the menu item in actionBar. Is there a way in which i can get this working other that extending it to `ActionBarActivity`?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way in which i can get this working other that extending it to ActionBarActivity?

The `v7` edition of the `MediaRouteActionProvider` only works with the `appcompat-v7` version of the action bar, which in turn requires `ActionBarActivity`, `Theme.AppCompat`, and kin.

I have [a cross-port of `MediaRouteActionProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-mediarouter) that works with the native action bar.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in your fragment `onCreate`